# Multi-store with shared inventory in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multistore

I'm trying to find the best approach to a woocommerce integration and could use some advice as I'm not 100% with the system. Basically there are 3 stores that will all share the site, each sharing products but some only offering 75% of the catalogue.

What would be the best way of handling this? I need the user to be able to pick a store location prior to entering the shop, with the relevant store's items being displayed thereafter.

The main thing is allowing all 3 to feed from one stock list but simply lock out some categories based on the selected store location.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WooCommerce on standard WordPress installation cannot run multiple stories. To solve your task, you can use [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) installation and [WooCommerce Multistore plugin](https://woomultistore.com/).

In this case, you can have 3 sites like shop1.my-shop.com, shop2.my-shop.com, shop3.my-shop.com with common WooCommerce database, but separate stock management.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I considered that, but separate stock management isn't required as it's a food outlet. I only need to be able to trim the catalogue if the user selects a store that, for example, doesn't have a salad bar.

Comment: You cannot have several shop pages in one single site. What you can do, assign categories like shop-1, shop-2, shop-3 and create several pages showing only this categories via shortcodes. But - in many cases WooCommerce returns to the shop page, where all your products will be presented.

Comment: A Wordpress Multisite network doesn't have to use Subdomains or Subdirectories. You can also have unique domain names entirely for each of the sub-sites within the network. For example: The networks mother-site being: www.mother.com and each of its sub-sites being: www.child1.com, www.child2.com etc.

Each sub-site would have its own inventory on a Multisite, however what you could do is take use of the API's and Webhooks that are built into WooCommerce which could hook into a third-party inventory system from each on the sub-sites WooCommerce. That way all your inventory is in one place.